# 'Live' Slider value into label

Tags: c#, slider, windows

I've made an app that allowes me to control a Microsoft NXT 2.0 Mindstorms robot and I've recently added a slider that I want to use to set the current engine speed instead of having a fixed value, so I need help.

Here I have the XAML of the label and slider that I want to use:

```
<Slider x:Name="Speed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Orientation="Vertical" Height="187" Maximum="90" Minimum="-90" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="5" TickPlacement="BottomRight" AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" MouseUp="Speed_MouseUp" BorderBrush="#00000000" Background="#00000000" Foreground="#FF858585">
<Label x:Name="Current_Speed" Content="Currently: " HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,478,257" Width="60" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="Black" />
```

I want `Current_Speed` to write `Currently: {SliderValue}` I want it to write the current value of the slider instantly as I move my slider up or down like you can do with the ToolTip option.

Any ideas?

(Bear in mind, I'm not very skilled, so detailed solutions would be much appreciated)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively easy. The "trick" is that you need to use two different `Label` objects, which you can aggregate together using a `StackPanel` container.

For the second `Label` object, just set the `Label`'s `Content` attribute like this:

```
Content="{Binding ElementName=Speed, Path=Value}"
```

The whole thing will look something like this:

```
<Slider x:Name="Speed"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Margin="40,58,0,0"
        Width="30" Height="187"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        Maximum="90" Minimum="-90"
        SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10"
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="5" TickPlacement="BottomRight"
        AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight"
        MouseUp="Speed_MouseUp"
        BorderBrush="#00000000" Background="#00000000" Foreground="#FF858585" />
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,257" Height="29">
  <Label x:Name="Current_Speed_Text"
       Content="Currently: "
       HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
       Foreground="Black" />
  <Label x:Name="Current_Speed"
       Content="{Binding ElementName=Speed, Path=Value}"
       HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
       Foreground="Black" />
</StackPanel>
```

Note: I have rearranged the layout a bit to ensure the UI elements are properly visible, and have reformatted the XAML itself to aid in readability.

I will also suggest that you use some other mechanism for controlling layout than setting the `Margin` values. The `Margin` attribute is very good for ensuring adequate space between elements, but it's not very good at accommodating flexible *layout* of elements, as it usually requires hand-modifying the margin values as other element characteristics change (e.g. font size, number of characters in the text, etc.).

Likewise, you should use `Width` and `Height` sparingly. They have similar problems.

In other words, if you apply the above suggestion to your XAML and it doesn't seem to work, it's because the `Label` is currently being laid out in such a way that the extra "speed value" text can't be seen.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am currently unable to try this out, but from the logic behind the 'Text' it seems to make sense for me (Unless I'm miss understanding). You'll hear from me on monday :) Thank you

Comment: @DeliciousCake: Please do not ask new questions by adding them to an existing question. Post a whole new question. Note that this is primarily for _your_ benefit; many fewer people will see the edit here (at this point, possibly only me until if and when someone stumbles across your question looking for a similar answer), but when you post a new question, it will have exposure to the full roster of the StackOverflow community.

Comment: @DeliciousCake: that said (above), having now reviewed your edit, I will note that the idiomatic way to approach this in WPF is for you to have a property of some "model" object bound to the `Slider.Value` property, so that it's automatically updated as the slider changes (and vice a versa). In very simple scenarios, it is IMHO acceptable to simply use the `Slider.Value` property directly; i.e. `if (Speed.Value > 0) ...`.

Comment: Thank you and my apologies, I have removed the edit and will make question answered now. Thank you for your help.